# row number based on field data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table and data

```
docRefID docExternalContent
 1       'a'
 1       'b'
 1       'c'
 2       'd'
 2       'e'
```

I want to know if it's possible that query will insert additional colum  rowNumber and auto increment based on docRefID e.g

```
docRefID docExternalContent rowNumber
 1       'a'                1  
 1       'b'                2 
 1       'c'                3
 2       'd'                1
 2       'e'                2
```

and so on.... I tried using ROW_NUMBER() OVER but it is working independent of docRefID.

Any help will be appricated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY docRefID ORDER BY docExternalContent)
```

Answer (score 3):

> I tried using ROW_NUMBER() OVER but it is working independent of docRefID.

Try this:

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY docRefID ORDER BY docExternalContent)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  row_number() over (partition by docRefId order by docExternalContent) as rn
,       *
from    YourTable
```